# Listing named ranges resulting in error #REF

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

These are 4 ranges (demo ranges). As you can see, the selected range is named as numbers2. Similarly, a5:a9 is numbers1, b2:b3 is alphabets1 and d2:d3 is alphabets2. I am displaying the named ranges in another sheet in same workbook.
Here's the code :

```
Sub namedRanges()
Dim nm As Name, n As Long, y As Range, z As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim sheet_name As String: sheet_name = InputBox("Provide the name of the worksheet where to list all the named ranges")
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = sheet_name

Set z = ActiveSheet
n = 2
With z
    .[a1:xfd104856].ClearContents
    .[a1:b1] = [{"Name","Refers to"}]
    For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        .Cells(n, 1).End(xlUp)(2) = nm.Name
        .Cells(n, 2).End(xlUp)(2) = "'" & nm.RefersTo
        n = n + 1
    Next nm
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Everything is working fine, except I am getting some extra named ranges which aren't there in the worksheet.

[image]

See, the new worksheet which is created. and there are two columns created. But I should get 4 named ranges, instead I am getting more.

Any thing which is wrong in the code ?

Comment: May I ask *why* you need to list the ranges?

Comment: This is one of the questions in my internship assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ribbon > Formulas > Names Manager:

[image]

You would see anything, which is declared in the workbook and how it is declared. In your code you are looping through `ActiveWorkbook.Names` and in your screenshot you are showing only the names in the current worksheet.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't knew that. I deleted all the #REF ranges from the Names Manager, and now it is working perfectly fine. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @AmanDevrath - no need to be sorry for this :). You are welcome :)